# Is there a Criteria to get the most recent fix in time (and not the most accurate)

Tags: android, gps, locationmanager

This is the code I use to get the last known location without adding a listener. I don't want to drain the battery, so I used:

```
public static Location getLastLoc(Context context){

    Location loc = null;

    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String best = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    //Log.i("***", best);
    if (best != null) {
        loc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(best);
    }
    //Sometimes getLastKnownLocation return null (new device), so I use network as default when possible. 
    if (loc == null) {
        try {
            loc = locationManager
                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return loc;
}
```

I am currently trying this code and the best provider sounds to be the GPS.

Unfortuantely, I have moved from city A to city B this morning and I haven't got a GPS fix yet. (but GPS is turned ON)

So I still get the old city A while I am at city B, and the Network location knows city B (tested with Google Maps)

So, as I don't need accurate position, how would it be possible to get the latest fix in time (GPS is 3 hours old, and network is 10 minutes old)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to make use of listener to get last know location. Because of

```
          locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(best);
```

it will not make a call to GPS to get updated location this method only gives last known location to locationManager object. That's why your location is not updating.

Comment: Yes, it will make a call to the GPS object and return the last fix GPS had. I don't want to turn On GPS. I want to use last know location if relevant

Answer (score 0):

While waiting for a better answer, the only I made it work was to check if the latest known location is not older than one hour:

```
loc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(best);
if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - loc.getTime()) < DateUtils.HOUR_IN_MILLIS)
    return loc;

try {
    if (locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER) != null)
        loc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```